# Can I hard code facebook API access token in my mobile app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am trying to call FB conversions API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/) in my mobile app to report app events to FB. I generated the access token (grants permission to report conversion for my ad account) in FB developer website. Now can I hard code that access token in my mobile app code? If not, how can I make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mobile apps should not be given secrets since they can't keep them - eg an attacker could use HTTP proxy tools to steal it. A better option would be to start by doing this if possible:

- User logs in to mobile app and the app gets a token
- Mobile app uses the token to get data from its own API
- Configure Facebook secret / credentials in your API, not your mobile app

You can then double hop messages to Facebook via your own API and secrets are managed securely:

- Mobile app calls an endpoint on its own API with the app token
- API gets a separate Facebook token and forwards the message to Facebook